# Alter a stream received via webRTC PeerConnection with AudioNodes of Web Audio API

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api

A complementary question to [Send MediaStream object with Web Audio effects over PeerConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431333/send-mediastream-object-with-web-audio-effects-over-peerconnection).

So far I've tried connecting remote stream to AudioContext.destination:

```
      var remoteSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(webRTCStream);
      var delayFilter = context.createDelay(10.0);
      var destination = context.destination;
      remoteSource.disconnect(destination);
      remoteSource.connect(delayFilter);
      delayFilter.connect(destination);
```

connecting to MediaStreamDestination and then to context.destination

```
     var destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
     delayFilter.connect(destination);
     destination.connect(context.destination);
```

I've even tried to intercept the track from the html element it self (which works perfectly for html5 <audio> tag)

```
  myAudio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(webRtcStream);

  var remoteSource = context.createMediaElementSource(myAudio);
  var delayFilter = context.createDelay(10.0);
  var destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();

  remoteSource.disconnect(context.destination);
  remoteSource.connect(delayFilter);
  delayFilter.connect(destination);
  destination.connect(context.destination);
```

However, none of them works in either Chrome or Firefox... Am i missing something? or it is not supposed to work/not implemented?

Comment: AFAIR this should work.

Comment: Modifying a stream that comes from another peer will NOT work in Chrome(known issue and bug). However, it should work in Firefox(I have done so with it in the past).

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Do you know the number of the issue in Chromium?

Comment: Yeah, I address this in another [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287054/chrome-wont-play-webaudio-getusermedia-via-webrtc-peer-js) and [here is the crbug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121673)